# How to show a div when user is logged in and on their profile but disable it when they go on some other user profile

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to figure out how I can disable the upload picture functionality on a profile that isn't my own. The user should only be able to view the upload button on their own profile and not other profiles.

```
<?php
    if(logged_in() === true && user_id_from_username($username) === true && isset($_GET['username']) === true){ 
    $username  = $_GET['username'];
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.profile_wrapp').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.select_buttons').fadeIn('fast');
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.select_buttons').fadeOut('fast'); });
</script>

<?php   
    }else{
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.select_buttons').hide();    
</script>

<?php   
    }
?>
```

Comment: if ($user_id == $currentlyViewingProfileId) { // add code here }

Comment: Can you somehow rephrase that I'm not entirely understanding, thanks

Comment: You need to grab the current users id, and use an if statement to display the upload on there profile or else don't show it. You can also use session variables to store the user ID so its accessible across the site.

Comment: Can you show me a code, ie, if it is their profile show button if not don't. their i'm using a method that identifies the user from username example: profile.php?username='$username'

Comment: @user2676472 I have already shown you the code, all you need to do is change a variable and add the code for the button...

Comment: is $currentlyViewingProfileId a built in php variable?

Comment: What error are you getting @user2676472 ?

Comment: There is no error I'm trying to remove the upload picture button when the user is on a profile that is not their own.

Comment: @JimL In your feedback I should create a new column the database called profile ID and then make a variable named $currentlyViewingProfileId

Comment: @user2676472 In order to display a profile you will have to have a $currentlyViewingProfileId variable, what you call it is up to you to decide. I just chose a name which would properly describe what data it should contain. So compare the id of the profile you're displaying to the id of the user, and if they match you show the personal profile fields.

Comment: Brillioto - Thanks Jimmy Boii

Comment: Btw: that was what I wrote in the first comment ^^

Comment: I'm going to have to add a table column in the damn database however, it just has to be done. - Just one person being driven nutts. :D